# Identify activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to know which activity calls current activity.I have three activity namely A,B and C. i am calling activity C from A or B. In activity C i want to know which activity calls A or B.

I used bundle to identify activity but i dont want this.. Is any other smart way to find my case?

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getCallingActivity()
```